# Doubt about square contained in a circle when show that $\mathcal{T}_{1}=\mathcal{T}_{2}$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following

$$(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \mathcal{T}_{1})=(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{\text{us}}) \times (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{\text{us}})=(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{T}_{\text{us}})=(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \mathcal{T}_{2})$$

I want to prove that $\mathcal{T}_{1}=\mathcal{T}_{2}$

if $A\in \mathcal{T}_{1}$ then $A$ is union of open rectangles, let $(a, b) \in A$ so there is a rectangle $R$ s.t. $(a, b)\in R \subseteq A$ As the union of squares results in a rectangle then there exists a square $R'$ with center at $(a, b)$ such that $(a, b)\in R' \subseteq R \subseteq A$ and since we can inscribe a circle in a square then there exists $\epsilon >0$ s.t. $(a, b) \in B_{\epsilon}(a, b) \subseteq  R' \subseteq R \subseteq A$ then A is a ball union and $A \in \mathcal{T}_{2}$

The reciprocal is analogous considering that we can inscribe a square in a ball.

In this second way it is not clear to me how I can prove that a ball is contained in a square and vice versa.

Perhaps an aid to demonstrate this is to consider the case where the square is centered at the origin, there it is observed that the ball is inside and is moved to the point $(a, b)$, but how?

any help for these ideas?

Comment: Can you define what $\mathcal{T}_1, \mathcal{T}_2, \mathcal{T}_{us}$ are? I'm very confused about what you mean by inscribing a circle in a square as well. Do you mean that we can cover an open ball with a countable union of squares/rectangles or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your notation that, letting $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathcal{T}_1$ refers to the topology generated by the basis consisting of open squares of the form $B_\infty (x, r)$, while $\mathcal{T}_2$ refers to the topology generated by the basis consisting of open balls of the form $B_2 (x, r)$, where $x \in X$ and $r > 0$. Both are metric topologies, one induced by the metric $d_1 (x, y) = \max \{|x_2 - x_1|, |y_2 - y_1| \}$ and the other by the Euclidean metric $d_2 (x, y) = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$. To show $\mathcal{T}_1 = \mathcal{T}_2$, we start with the following useful lemma:

> If, for each $x \in X$ and each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B_d (x, \delta) \subseteq B_e (x, \varepsilon)$, then the topology induced on $X$ by $d$ is finer than the topology induced on $X$ by $e$.

The proof of this is straightforward: let $B_e (x, r > 0)$ be an arbitrary basis element for the metric topology induced by $e$; let $y \in B_e (x, r)$ be arbitrary. Since $B_e (x, r)$ is obviously open in the topology induced by $e$ and contains $y$, there must exist some basis element $B_e (y, r') \subseteq B_e (x, r)$. Now, use the hypothesis to guarantee some $s > 0$ such that $B_d (y, s) \subseteq B_e (y, r') \implies B_d (y, s) \subseteq B_e (x, r)$. This shows $B_e (x, r)$ is open in the topology induced by $d$, as desired.

With this lemma in place, it is now easy to address the original problem. First we let $d = d_1$ and $e = d_2$. For arbitrary $x \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $B_d \left( x, \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \subseteq B_e (x, \varepsilon)$. Now we let $d = d_2$ and $e = d_1$. For arbitrary $x \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $B_d (x, \varepsilon) \subseteq B_e (x, \varepsilon)$.

It follows that the two induced topologies are identical.